# PHP require and require_once fails on relative path

Tags: php

We have moved our hosting from server which hosted `PHP 5.6` to a new server which hosts `PHP 7.0.` After the migration, we've noticed the following issue:

> PHP Warning: include_once(../classes/ClassA.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/addons/addon.php php on line 37

I understand it should work with

```
include_once __DIR__."/../classes/ClassA.php";
```

But I don't understand why it worked on previous server and not on new one. Are there any `php.ini` changes that were allowing it to work without __DIR __ prefix?

Comment: Note: missing `.` for concatenation between `__dir__` and string.

Comment: Also check how the script is called, if you call a php file in `/var/www/html/addons/` from another php file in the same directory, `__DIR__` will be different than when you call that file from completely different directory.

Comment: @Syscall Added the concatenation, my bad!

Comment: @kevin This is mainly a problem that appeared when migrated to a new server. Files and database are exactly the same, the PHP version differs and probably a php.ini. Is there any setting out there that should make it work like on previous server? The reason I ask is because we've got over 2000 files that definitely need some refactoring as it was written by many different developers, and something might not unnoticed.

Comment: Simply moving files to another server does not guarantee equal behaviour. The server configuration could be different, causing your code to behave differently, environment variable may be different. You say the PHP version is different, that can cause huge changes, it's definitely not something to dismiss as not a likely cause of issues. Try installing a clean VM exactly like the old server and see if it works there, then try slowly making the VM more like your new server and see when the code breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Use **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** instead of `_DIR_`. Remove the path components ../../ and point absolutely to a file using the $_SERVER variable.

**Or**

Create a **BASEPATH** constant with value of absolute path to your site's root directory. Which you can use to absolutely point to an include file. If you move to another server, just update the value of that variable if needed.

Comment: This is the path of least resistance when it comes to PHP, it's just too much headache to keep track of the current working directory and when it changes (calling another file) and when not (calling a method in an included file) and let code depend on it.

Answer (score -1):

> try `realpath()` function..!

```
include_once realpath(__DIR__."/../classes/ClassA.php");
```

The `realpath()` function returns the absolute pathname.

This function removes all symbolic links (like `/./`, '`/../`' and extra '`/`') and returns the absolute pathname.

This function returns FALSE on failure.

Comment: Why do you recommend to use this function? Please add an explanation.